# how to make parametric equation of cube

Tags: parametric

this is my hyperbolic equation

$y = x^2$

then convert to paramteric equation, like this:

$x = u$

$y = u^2$

so i insert the equation into x and y Axis Generator

```
x: u
y: u
z: 0
```

the output is: **2D hyperbolic object**

when i insert `v` parameter into z Axis

the output is: **3D hyperbolic object**

my question is how to make 3D cube using parametric equation and how to insert it into the Generator.

any help thank youu :-) I LOVE YOU

another exemple:

```
x: cos(u)
y: sin(u)
z: v
```

the output is: **pipe**

where:

```
u minimal: 0
u maximal: 6.28

v minimal: 0
v maximal: 1
```

Comment: Well, you could start by considering the walls of the cube. How would you make the floor? Something like $z=0$ ?

Comment: i make floor using simple parametric u and v. but hard to find how make the walls. is it possible make the walls as same as when i make circle. i don't know, is my problem about parametric or   not.

Comment: thank you for your respon. what should i do with those equations? because hard to read the equation without `u` and `v` parameter. @MohammadZuhairKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a solid cube of side-length $a\in\Bbb R^+$ centred at the origin would be:

$|x|\le a/2\\|y|\le a/2\\|z|\le a/2$

Parameterize it as:

$x=u, |u|\le a/2\\y=v, |v|\le a/2\\z=w, |w|\le a/2$

Comment: i cannot read your equation. i input x = v ≤ a/2 and y = v ≤a/2 and then z = a/2 and still doesn't work @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Carefully not the modulus sign around $v. y=v, |v|\le a/2\implies -a/2\le v\le a/2$, in other words $y=v,v_{min}=-a/2,v_{max}=a/2$

Comment: still not work well sir, .. i use free Blender software to make the object.. still confuse for weeks @ShubhamJohri